# Three-finger lookup order wrong?

Tags: dictionary

When I use three-finger lookup, this is what I got.

[image]

The order of the results is wrong (i.e., different from my settings shown below), and many dictionaries are missing!

[image]

However, I open the dictionary app and look the same word up inside, the order of the results is correct, the same as my settings.

How do I correct the result order of three-finger lookups?

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling any dictionaries you don't specifically need. three-finger/force-click lookups only show a few results, not all of them. You can open the dictionary and search the word there as an alternative. This seems to be a bug on Apple's side, so there isn't much else you can do. If its any consolation, I have this problem as well, so you aren't alone.